# R.string error cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

I'm getting the error "cannot be resolved or is not a field" on this line of code.

```
int textString = R.string.start;
```

The strings.xml file is located in the res > layout directory so it's not in another package. 
Why is this error occurring even after I clean and/or rebuild the project?

```
import com.example.lab08_2hw.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView av; //UI reference
    int textString = R.string.start;
    int backgroundColor = Color.DKGRAY;
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    // Create runnable for posting results to the UI thread
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            av.setText(textString);
            av.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        av = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.computation_status);
        Button actionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action1);
        actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                doWork();
            }
        });
    }
    //example of a computationally intensive action with UI updates
    private void doWork() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textString=R.id.start;
                backgroundColor = Color.DKGRAY;
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                computation(1);
                textString=R.id.first;

                backgroundColor = Color.BLUE;
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                computation(2);
                textString=R.id.second;
                backgroundColor = Color.GREEN;
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    final static int SIZE=1000; //large enough to take some time
    double tmp;
    private void computation(int val) {
    for(int ii=0; ii<SIZE; ii++)
        for(int jj=0; jj<SIZE; jj++)
            tmp=val*Math.log(ii+1)/Math.log1p(jj+1);
        }
    }
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, HandlerUpdateUi!</string>
<string name="app_name">HandlerUpdateUi</string>
<string name="action">Press to Start</string>
<string name="start">Starting...</string>
<string name="first">First Done</string>
<string name="second">Second Done</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of flaws in your code. The ones that could be relevant for your problem are below:
First change your strings.xml location to `res/values`.  `res > layout` directory should be used for your layouts.
 
Second change `int textstring` to `String` textstring.
And third call this line `String textString = R.string.start;` inside `onCreate()` method.
The place you are initiliazing it right now is wrong.

Comment: Close, but 1) String not string and 2) nothing wrong with the location of the assignment.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for correcting string to String. My smart device acts like it is smarter than me, changing upper-case to lower-case when it feels like it. As for strings.xml location, putting it under res->values is definitely a better practise.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 getResources().getString(R.string.start);
```

Comment: I'm trying to pull the string "start" from the strings.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Put your string.xml file to values folder.
then use the following code to get string from string.xml file

getResources().getString(R.string.start);